# Refactoring RSpec test to only have one require at top of file (Ruby only, no Rails)

Tags: ruby, rspec, refactoring, tdd

I'm writing RSpec tests for a Ruby tic tac toe game I built. The test is passing after it was failing initially, so that's a good sign. This is the computer_spec.rb file:

```
require 'computer'
require 'board'

describe "the computer selects the winning move as spot 3" do
  it "when spots 1 and 2 are chosen" do
    computer = Computer.new
    board = Board.new
    computer.winning_move(board, [1,2]).should eq(3)
  end
end
```

Now, since it's a computer_spec.rb file, it should really only have ***require 'computer'*** at the top of this file. I mean sure it works but I want to become very good with RSpec and do things the best and most concise way.

Naturally, the Computer Class uses ***board.rb*** in the winning_move method. winning_move is passed two arguments, board and computer. The BOARD itself is a hash (the tile being the key, and the X or O being the value). It's a little bit of code but you can see board.rb here: https://github.com/DavidPardy/ttt_v2/blob/master/lib/board.rb

I tried to hardcode the hash in to computer_spec.rb, but no go. One of the more common errors is 'uninitialized constant Board', which makes sense...I think.

So what would be the best way to go about this to only have require 'computer' at the top of this file?

Any input is appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: I just used spec_helper.rb, not sure why I wasn't using that from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Some Options:

- Put Computer and Board class definitions in one file and include that file.
- Add board as an autoloaded file
- Add ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/somefolder"